# Not getting data of GITHUB api using npm module sync-request

Tags: node.js, git, npm, github-api

I am trying to get data of below url using sync-request module.

```
https://api.github.com/repos/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/stargazers
```

I get the data when i call it in browser or through postman.
But i am getting 403 forbidden error when calling it using sync-request in my node api.

My code looks like this.

```
 var request = require("sync-request");

 var response = request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/stargazers', {
                headers: {},
                json: true
            });
```

I am able to fetch data of many other api's but not this one. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response body already contains the explanation:

> Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header (http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required). Check https://developer.github.com for other possible causes.

It will work like:

```
var response = request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/stargazers', {
    headers: { 'User-Agent': 'Request' },
    json: true
});
```

The use of `sync-request` is strongly discouraged because synchronousness is achieved via a hack and may block the process for a long time.

For sequential execution `request-promise` can be used together with `async..await`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an access token along with the GitHub API call
like  this

[https://api.github.com/repos/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/stargazers?access_token=f33d1f112b7883456c990028539a22143243aea9]

As you say the API works in the browser it should not be an issue.

When you use too many calls through the GitHub API they they give the following message

`{
  "message": "API rate limit exceeded for 192.248.24.50. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting"
}`

To overcome this issue you can use an access token using an access token  you can to access the private repositories in your account as well .
Here is the link for to get an access token [https://github.com/settings/developers]